# WFS layer not displayed in OL3 when loading as GeoJSON from geoserver

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to load my layer from Geoserver as WFS layer in my OL3 application.

Here is my code to create WFS layer:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=main:Building_WGS&' +
        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&';
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
  }))
});


var vector1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});
```

To make my code complete here is the code where I have created map object:

```
var centerpos = [84.2, 28.2];
var newpos = ol.proj.transform(centerpos,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:900913');
var maxExtent = [80.05844110726194,26.34796712822462,88.2015218371264,30.44742963310623];

var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [baseLayerOSM, vector1],
      target: 'map',
      //controls: [new CustomControl()],
      view: new ol.View({
        extent:ol.proj.transformExtent(maxExtent, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913'),
        projection : 'EPSG:900913', // OSM projection
        center : newpos,
        minZoom:7,
        zoom: 7
      })
    });
```

I can see the OSM layer in my map. But I can't see the layer Building_WGS. I have a workspace main in geoserver.

When I copy the URL

```
'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=main:Building_WGS&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&';
```

I can see the JSON contents.

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong in my code?

I even tried to add crossOrigin:"Anonymous" but that doesn't help either.

HELP please

AJ

Comment: Check you developer tools while using the maps. Any error messages? Any failed requests?

Comment: There is no error message or nothing I have already checked on Developer tool

Comment: Are any features added to the source?

Comment: No I am just trying to view my layer as Vector Layer. I am not doing anything else.  I think the code should just work fine but for some reason I can't see the layer and there is no error message

Comment: is there any other way to add vector layer?

Comment: Do vectorSource.getFeatures().getArray() after the map has loaded, to confirm that the features are loaded properly.

Comment: I got error message on the statement: TypeError: vectorSource.getFeatures(...).getArray is not a function

Comment: Ah, vectorSource.getFeatures() should be enough.

Comment: What am I suppose to get with that statement? I get nothing in my debugger or if I use the statement like alert(vectorSource.getFeatures()) I get nothing.

Comment: It's to verify if your issue is about loading the features or displaying them. If you get an empty array, you haven't loaded any features.

Comment: But why can I see the json file when I use the URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=main:Building_WGS&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326. what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't get it what's wrong with it. It's giving me a headache now :(

Comment: It could be a number of different issues, you should provide more details. For starters, does getFeatures return an empty Array or something else? Have you verified that it's not a CORS issue?

Comment: I removed the funtion in my URL like this:
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  crossOrigin:"Anonymous",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
        'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=genesis:Building_WGS&' +
        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326'
});
Even though the alert message alert(vectorSource.getFeatures()); shows nothing but I can at least see the layer on my map.
Thank you. Now my next step is to zoom-in to specific building when the user pass the id to the app
Thanks Alvin Lindstam

AJ

Comment: how do I zoom-in to specific building id? can you suggest how can i do it?